# How can I run only one test for only one spec file in RubyMine

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara, rubymine

I'd like to run only one test for only one spec file in request folder in RubyMine. But I can test only all files with spec:request task. Can anyone help me to run only particular test?

Answer (score 7):

If I understand your question correctly, you can right-click on the test or spec name and click `Run {test_name}`.

Alternatively, you should be able to place your mouse cursor inside the text of the test name and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>.

Comment: But I'd like not to run rb file, but run it with spec

Comment: When I right-click on the spec name (eg., `describe "when first name is not present"`) and click `'Run'`, it only runs that example. Is that not what you want to do?

Comment: Does this only work on "describe"?  I am using capybara scenarios like
scenario: "I want this to work when I right click" do

Is there anywhere to edit the rubymine parser for this I wonder?